# How humid should the air be to avoid epistaxis (i.e., nosebleed) induced by air dryness?

Tags: air-quality, epistaxis--bloody-nose, scratch-scratching, humidifier

Many websites indicates that excessively dry air may cause epistaxis (i.e., nose bleeding).

[Example](http://www.healthline.com/symptom/nosebleed):

> Dry air is the most common cause of nosebleeds. Living in a dry climate and using a central heating system can dry out the nasal membranes, which are tissues inside the nose. This dryness causes crusting inside the nose. Crusting may itch or become irritated. If your nose is scratched or picked, it can bleed.

How humid should the air be to avoid epistaxis?

Answer (score 2):

Sites vary, but most mention a median range of between 30-40% humidity.

[40-50% Humidity](http://www.highqproducts.com/nosebleeds.php)

> During extremely cold weather, your home loses humidity to the
>   outdoors and may drop as low as 5%. By comparison, typical humidity in
>   the Sahara Desert is about 25%! Generally, one does not want to have a
>   home humidity any lower than 30%. Optimal comfort is considered to be
>   achieved at 40-55% humidity. Nosebleeds also occur in hot dry climates
>   with low humidity, or when there is a change in the seasons.

[Above 30%](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_humidity)

> Indoor relative humidities should be kept above 30% to reduce the
>   likelihood of the occupant’s nasal passages drying out,[7][8]
>   Humans can be comfortable within a wide range of humidities depending
>   on the temperature—from thirty to seventy percent[9]—but ideally
>   between 50%[10] and 60%.[11] Very low humidity can create discomfort,
>   respiratory problems, and aggravate allergies in some individuals. In
>   the winter, it is advisable to maintain relative humidity at 30
>   percent or above.[12] Extremely low (below 20%) relative humidities
>   may also cause eye irritation.[13]

[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/first-aid/tc/nosebleeds-prevention)

> Keep the heat low [60°F (16°C) to 64°F (18°C)] in sleeping areas

Comment: "Extremely low (below 20%) relative humidities may also cause eye irritation" But then passengers on board planes where the humidity is around 10% usually do just fine...

Comment: @CountIblis they "usually" do? Maybe you do - I don't. Dry eyes are a pretty normal thing people experience on flights. http://www.who.int/ith/mode_of_travel/chad/en/